# Simple AM Radio Troubleshooting

Tags: diy, transmitter, am, equipment-troubleshooting

I just got all the parts to make a simple AM transmitter from [Scitoys](https://scitoys.com/scitoys/scitoys/radio/am_transmitter.html). I followed the instructions from different websites and they still don't work. I don't know why it's not working. On my breadboard, the power rail is working. I used a multimeter to test various parts of the circuit. The transformer seems to work. There is some resistance with ohms. I don't hear anything on my AM receiver. Where do I even begin?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115948/discussion-on-question-by-derpy-simple-am-radio-troubleshooting).

Comment: @MikeWaters not to be mean to Derpy, but you moved a close vote to chat, that seems a bit unwise?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hmmm, I see there are two close votes, "This question doesn’t meet a Amateur Radio Stack Exchange guideline" instead of the other, more specific reasons. Perhaps I was too quick to do what the pop-up moderator instructions said to do?

Comment: @MikeWaters that might be an artefact of me picking the custom reason:
*I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a design that actually doesn't work.*

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't understand the reason why you voted that way, since this isn't the only question that fits your close reason. *Some of those comments should have been answers*.

Comment: I would've posted "replace the circuit with something that might work" if Derpy would not have assumed all the time that it's just something they need to tweak to fix; I don't see how posting it as an answer rather than as a comment would've changed that. Together with the low future-reader value of this question, I'd prefer to close a "I have an unproven circuit that doesn't work" as a question that is really not about ham radio nor even generally a solvable problem than to answer this.

Comment: The thing is (and that's not clear from the close reason without context): the design used here isn't "generally in the right spirit, but needs to be fixed to work"; it's based on a working principle assumption that falls short; it also applies a 9V to a 5V component which quite probably instantly burns. There's nothing to be learned from this design, I'm afraid – "can't make my tennis shoe transmit FM" is about as exciting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how to give proper credit but I figured it out with your help. I'd like to thank all of you for helping me. It really means a lot even though it was a bit rough. Don't push away newcomers. But anyways you've all been a great help! Each one of you gets two brownies.

The issue was the oscillator. Either it was dead on arrival or scitoys misspoke on the proper voltage. The new one megahertz crystal full can oscillator I got off of Amazon requires 5 volts. I put three AA batteries together and my AM receiver went instantly quiet. I knew it was transmitting something and I was so excited. I hooked up my phone to play some music and I was blown away at the quality. It sounded way better than I expected. I'm actually kind of shocked at how good it is.

This is my first step in making a super awesome AM radio. The next steps for me are creating different modules to create the best signal possible for output. The modulator, amplifier, and antenna design.